# Placing T-shaped tetrominoes on a n × n board.

Tags: number-theory

You have an infinite stack of T-shaped tetrominoes (composed of four squares of side length 1), and an n × n board. You are allowed to place some tetrominoes on the board, possibly rotated, as long as no two tetrominoes overlap and no tetrominoes extend off the board. For which values of n can you cover the entire board?(source :Canadian Junior Mathematical Olympiad 2022 p2)

how I tried:

1. Since,  each tetrominoe have 4 squares, the total number of squares is even therefore n is even.
2. I found experimentally that 4 is the smallest value  of n. Therefore every multiple of 4 can also be a value of n(assume an 4 × 4 square to be a unit square and try to form squares with it.)

But I am not sure if every n is a multiple of 4 or there are some other forms, and by 'some other form' I mean if  n = 4k + 2.

Comment: I do not think this is possible for $n=6$.  Perhaps the reason for this can be extended

Answer (score 1):

Color the board like a checkerboard.  Each T covers three squares of one color and one of the other.  An odd number of Ts then cannot cover and equal number of squares of each color, so the area must be a multiple of $8$.  This requires that the side of the board be a multiple of $4$.

Comment: can you simplify this sentence further " equal number of squares of each color, so the area must be a multiple of 8".

Comment: Every T has odd number of black squares. Board has even number of black squares. Then number of T is even.